# Delete all non strings values in a array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of arrays with only str and nan values, like:

```py
x = numpy.recarray(
    [('A', 'B', nan, nan),
     ('B', nan, nan, nan),
     ('A', 'B', 'H', 'Z')],
     dtype=[('D1', 'O'), ('D2', 'O'),  
            ('D3', 'O'), ('D4', 'O')])
```

and I'm looking for an efficient way to drop all the nan values, and stay with arrays with variable number of elements. The nan values are float type.

```py
type(x[0][3])
out: float
```

Thank you in advance estimates

Comment: just to confirm, lists or numpy arrays? `x` here is a list. Also, you lose a lot of advantages of numpy if you go for variable length lists inside them, because numpy has to store them as native objects.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh arrays my friend, my mistake

Comment: @Divakar its not-a-number float type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a recarray of shape (3,) and 4 fields:

```
In [85]: x = np.array( 
    ...:     [('A', 'B', np.nan, np.nan), 
    ...:      ('B', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan), 
    ...:      ('A', 'B', 'H', 'Z')], 
    ...:      dtype=[('D1', 'O'), ('D2', 'O'),   
    ...:             ('D3', 'O'), ('D4', 'O')])                                                          
In [86]: x                                                                                               
Out[86]: 
array([('A', 'B', nan, nan), ('B', nan, nan, nan), ('A', 'B', 'H', 'Z')],
      dtype=[('D1', 'O'), ('D2', 'O'), ('D3', 'O'), ('D4', 'O')])
In [87]: x.shape                                                                                         
Out[87]: (3,)
In [88]: x['D1']                                                                                         
Out[88]: array(['A', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)
In [89]: x['D3']                                                                                         
Out[89]: array([nan, nan, 'H'], dtype=object)
```

You can't make that ragged.

But you can make it a 2d array from that, and then do a list comprehension:

```
In [93]: xx = np.array(x.tolist())                                                                       
In [94]: xx                                                                                              
Out[94]: 
array([['A', 'B', 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['B', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['A', 'B', 'H', 'Z']], dtype='<U3')
In [95]: [[i for i in row if i!='nan'] for row in xx]                                                    
Out[95]: [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'H', 'Z']]
```

We could also do the comprehension on elements of the structured array:

```
In [101]: [[i for i in row if i is not np.nan] for row in x]                                             
Out[101]: [['A', 'B'], ['B'], ['A', 'B', 'H', 'Z']]
```

An element of `x` is tuple like.  Technically it is `np.void` (compound dtype record), but it iterates like a tuple.